# Is linkrot as big a concern within SE as without?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

Specifically, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130093/2483138) which feels like a (mostly) link-only answer.  At least one of the reasons link-only is bad is because we can't guarantee that the link will still point to valid information in the future (thus negating the answers usefulness).

If the link is to another answer inside SO, is that concern still there?  Is it acceptable to link to another answer using the same logic that applies when marking a question as a duplicate (i.e. if SE exists to find Question A, then it will exist to find Question B)?

Comment: SE posts are subject to deletion, if they don't meet quality standards.  Those posts wouldn't make good link candidates anyway.

Comment: If the whole answer is a link to another SO post, why not close the question as duplicate?

Comment: If another answer is worth mentioning as part of your own, then *cite the important details*. That way if the other post disappears (deletion) then at least you have those important details preserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, link-only answers that link to other posts on Stack Exchange sites are still a concern.

1. The post you're linking to can still disappear, even if the site itself is still there. Granted, if a post is so good that you're linking to it as an answer the odds are reduced, but I have seen links to deleted SO posts plenty of times.
2. There's the additional concern that if a link to another post answers a question, then maybe the question itself should have been just closed as a duplicate of the linked post. If it isn't an exact duplicate, then a link probably isn't enough to answer the question anyway.

Comment: This is why I tend to have little problem with converting answers to comments when they are no more than a link to another Stack Overflow answer. That preserves the link between the questions, may hint towards a duplicate, and the comment can be removed later if the other question / answer is deleted.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, those are usually an automatic convert to comment for me, if I notice where the link is going. Unless the link-only answer is accepted, then I take the extra step of closing as a duplicate. Can't get much more confirmation than that.